# TeamCity Call Url Build Step

Tags: asp.net, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to build and deploy files onto a IIS website using Web Deploy 3.

I would like to add a step to call a url when done so that the custom cache can be refreshed when the deployment is finished.

Is there a way I can add a build step to call a url?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would solve this using a command line script that hits the url, and one of TeamCity's command line runners.

The question is tagged asp.net so I assume you're on Windows.  Put this [Get-WebFile](http://poshcode.org/417) script in a [Powershell Build Runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/PowerShell).  Then call `Get-WebFile "http://yourwebapp.net/"` at the bottom.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  It's actually a very good solution and allows me to do more than just call a url now.  Just curious, how to I return an unsuccessful step if anything goes wrong?

Comment: Third hit from the top:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+fail+a+build+in+teamcity

Comment: How would I send credentials to a site using Integrated Windows authentication with this script?

Answer (score 8):

An even simpler method would be the same Powershell buildrunner step, but just use:

`(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://yourwebapp.net");`.

No dependencies on other scripts, just native Powershell. Anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

A newer, cleaner, just-as-simple method would be also using Powershell:

```
wget "http://yourwebapp.net"
```

`wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, supporting more options like settings the request timeout.

Full docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

*NB: On older environments you may want to set `-UseBasicParsing` to prevent parsing errors.*