# Using TeamCity build number in Buildmaster

Tags: teamcity, buildmaster

Is it possible to grab the build number from TeamCity and use that as a build number in BuildMaster?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by triggering the BuildMaster API's Builds_CreateBuild method from TeamCity which accepts a numeric build number. It should be fairly straightforward to make a GET request to the BuildMaster JSON API from TeamCity, see this question for a simple way to do so: [TeamCity Call Url Build Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317102/teamcity-call-url-build-step)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new build including the build number you need to firstly enable the api under settings. There is no 'enable' button as such, you just need to provide an arbitrary key for the api authentication (any literal will do, but presumably make it complex for best security!).

The JSON syntax for the creating a build is as follows:

```
http://buildmaster-server/api/json/Builds_CreateBuild?API_Key=abcde12345&Build_Number=123&Release_Number=0.0
```

This will actually create a new build on your build master server. This can then be triggered via Team City using Powershell with the powershell script inline such as:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://buildmaster-server/api/json/Builds_CreateBuild?API_Key=abcde12345&Build_Number=%build.number%&Release_Number=0.0&Application_Id=2" -UseBasicParsing
```

You can add further variables and call hundreds of BuildMaster API's using the above method. Full API documentation can be found here: http://inedo.com/support/documentation/buildmaster/reference/api-methods